# Proof of Integral Test - Question on existence of convergent series to start proof - Spivak Ch.22

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, solution-verification

The following is the proof of the Integral Test from *Spivak's Calculus - 2nd edition - Ch.22*.

[image]

I understand the majority of the proof, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the claim of:

"The existence of $\lim_{A \to \infty}\int_{1}^{A}f$ is equivalent to the convergence of the series $$\int_{1}^{2}f + \int_{2}^{3}f + \int_{3}^{4}f + \dots$$"

Since I was having trouble with the concept I've attempted to prove this claim, but it is here where I'm running into problems. So given the above conditions of the original theorem I could interpret $\int_{1}^{A}f$ as being the terms of a sequence. So let's define the terms as: $b_{A} = \int_{1}^{A}f$.

To continue on I asked myself "What does it mean for the series to converge?" Here it means that if I define $S_{A} = b_{1} + b_{2} + \dots + b_{A}$ (partial sum), then $$\lim_{A \to \infty}S_{A} = \sum_{A = 1}^{\infty}b_{A} = l$$ for some $l$.

From here the question I ask myself is "How to show a sequence converges?" from which I would answer with the standard definition of: For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a natural number $A > 0$ such that for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$, if $a > A$, then $|S_{a} - l| < \epsilon$. But this probably won't help me in this situation. I looked up previous proofs on the integral test and one of them dealt with this issue:

[Proof of integral test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831657/proof-of-integral-test)

but in that version the OP had the additional fact of: $\sum_{k=2}^n f(k) \le \int_1^n f(x) dx \lt \int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx \lt \infty$

I don't have this fact at my disposal. But I'm also attempting to prove this from my own formulation of the claim so perhaps I would've needed that to prove the original claim. But still I'm stuck on showing the original claim. What can I do to prove this?

**EDIT:** In the question I have incorrectly defined my $b_{n}$. The correct way they should be defined is in the comments, I'm leaving the mistake in the question in case others in the future make the same mistake.

Comment: You do have that fact - use the fact that $f$ is (1.)positive, (2.) decreasing, (3.) Each region of integration has length $n+1 - n = 1$

Comment: How do you know each region of integration is of length $1$?

Comment: @dc3rd Your sum of the $b_i$ is of the form $\int_1^2 f + \int_1^3 f + \cdots,$ when it should instead be of the form $\int_1^2 f + \int_2^3 f + \cdots.$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I see what you mean. Could I "possibly" rectify that by defining my sequence as $c_{A} = b_{A} - b_{A-1}$? as an example term: $c_{3} = b_{3} - b_{2} = \int_{1}^{3}f - \int_{1}^{2}f = \int_{1}^{3}f + \int_{2}^{1}f = \int_{2}^{3}f$ (flipping the integral). Or is this just over complicating things?

Comment: @dc3rd Yes. Equivalently, you would be defining $c_A = \int_{A-1}^A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann. Cool....But I'm still stuck on how to get this claim.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Break up your proof of equivalence into a proof of "if" and "only if". You should find it easy to prove that if $\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_1^A f$ exists, then the sum $\int_1^2 f + \int_2^3 f + \cdots$ also converges.

For the other direction, you must use the fact that $f$ is positive and decreasing.

---

As for the "fact that OP had", you would only need to prove that $f(k) \leq \int_{k-1}^{k} f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: I'm going to give it a go and will report back.

Comment: I think I figured out the first direction. I'll show the rough work because that would imply i I treated it right. I need to show $|S_{A} - l| < \epsilon$. Using how I defined $c_{A}$ in the comments, if I work backwards: $|S_{A} - l| = |\sum_{i = 1}^{A}c_{i} - l| = |c_{1} + c_{2} + \dots + c_{A} - l| = |b_{1} - b_{0} + b_{2} - b_{1} + \dots + b_{A} - b_{A-1} - l| = |b_{A} - b_{0} - l| < |b_{A} - l| < \epsilon$. The $|b_{A} - l| < \epsilon$ comes from us being given $\lim_{A \to \infty}\int_{1}^{A}f = \lim_{A \to \infty}b_{A}$ exists. So to do the proof I would start with the last part.

Comment: As for the second direction, I'm still a little stuck.